# Exportar a Excel - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, java-swing

Este es el código que utilizo para exportar a excel:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
    protected void btnExportarExcelActionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         JFileChooser seleccionar = new JFileChooser();
         File archivo;
         if (seleccionar.showDialog(null, "Exportar a Excel") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
             archivo = seleccionar.getSelectedFile();
             int cantFila = tbNivelArchivo.getRowCount();
             int cantColumna = tbNivelArchivo.getColumnCount();
             XSSFWorkbook wb;
             wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
             Sheet hoja = ((org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook) wb).createSheet(" ");
             try {
                    for (int i = -1; i < cantFila; i++) {
                        Row fila = hoja.createRow(i + 1);
                        for (int j = 0; j < cantColumna; j++) {
                            Cell celda = fila.createCell(j);
                            if (i == -1) {
                               celda.setCellValue(String.valueOf(tbNivelArchivo.getColumnName(j)));
                            } else {
                                celda.setCellValue(String.valueOf(tbNivelArchivo.getValueAt(i, j)));
                            }
                            wb.write(new FileOutputStream(archivo + ".xlsx"));
                        }
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exportacion exitosa");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vuelve a intentarlo");
                }
         }
    }
```

Si se genera el **excel** pero no se abre automaticamente.

Comment: La respuesta de @emed me parece correcta, si te sirvió puedes marcarla? :) de lo contrario comenta porque no te sirvió.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [Desktop.getDesktop().open(File file)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)), que segun la documentacion abre el archivo en la aplicacion asociada.

Cuando termines de generar tu archivo, llamas:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(archivo);
```

Y eso deberia abrir tu archivo en Excel si tienes instalado MS Office, o Calc si tienes LibreOffice, etc.